# archiving in small database tables

Tags: sql-server

At what scale of database growth does archiving become a necessity, and are there guidelines to show when it is required?

I manage an intranet which provides short news articles via about 40 targeted news groups. I have been asked to remove browsing access to articles older than 2 years, but to maintain access to these by an existing search interface.

One proposal is to hide records by using scheduled overnight tasks to remove out old news items to parallel archive tables. Given that the entire database is only about 5Gb, the entire set of 13000 news articles take up 17Mb, and there are indexes on the publication dates, is this approach advisable or will WHERE clauses based on dates suffise? Is there a rule of thumb here?

The db in question is SQL 2008, we add maybe 2000 news items per year, and there are no reported performance issues at present - this is purely 'future proofing'.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely is a candidate for doing the simplest possible thing, because the data involved is quite manageable. A *where* clause should be enough. You should have an index on the date column you want to use in the *where* clause, as that will probably be done in an online fashion.

---

IDK about the setup you have, but 5GB is enough to load in memory and still have room to spare. So you're well within what the system can handle.